# Adding a new row to a selection of rows in a section vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet split into sections and for each section there is an 'Add new line' where it adds to the existing rows in that section.

I've had a go at the Currentregion function that counts the rows but stuck on selecting the last row then adding one underneath.

The code so far is where I am able to add a new line but I'm looking for a more clean precise solution with CurrentRegion for each section - this can be done with the sBudgetLine parameter that is passed in.

```
Sub AddNewAllocToSpendLine(sBudgetLine As String, Optional sSheetName As String = c_Alloc2SpendSheetName)
'Adds new line to the list of allocated to spend

Dim c As Range
Dim s As String


    Worksheets(sSheetName).Activate

'get the budget line position
    Set c = Worksheets(sSheetName).Range("A:A").Find(sBudgetLine, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not (c Is Nothing) Then
        s = Trim(str(c.Row))
        Range("B" & Trim(str(c.Row))).Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select

        If Selection.Value = "Period" Then
            s = Trim(str(Selection.Row + 2))
        Else
            s = Trim(str(Selection.Row + 1))
        End If

        s = s & ":" & s
        Rows(s).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        s = Trim(str(Selection.Row))
        Range("E10").Copy
        Cells(Selection.Row, 5).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Range("A" & Trim(str(c.Row))).Select
    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For instance, if you know for sure your Range has data in A1, the use the following code:

```
Dim lastrow    as Integer

lastrow = Worksheets(sSheetName).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
Rows(lastrow + 1).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, get rid of all the selections. They are slow and prone to cause errors.

For example, instead of

```
Rows(s).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

use

```
Rows(s).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

Second, you don't need to cast the row number as string and trim it. The `&` causes them to be cast as string for you.

I removed the unnecessary lines with `'` and added comments with `''`.

```
Sub AddNewAllocToSpendLine(sBudgetLine As String, Optional sSheetName As String = "Sheet3") 'c_Alloc2SpendSheetName)
'Adds new line to the list of allocated to spend

Dim c As Range
Dim lastRow As Long 'I renamed s so it's more obvious what it does

''this is to make sure we're always on the right sheet
With Worksheets(sSheetName)

    'get the budget line position
    ''range("A:A") or columns(1) is really just a matter of taste
    Set c = .Columns(1).Find(sBudgetLine, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not (c Is Nothing) Then
        ''instead of selecting the cell in the last row, we find the index of the last row and use that instead
        's = Trim(Str(c.Row)) 'you don't use s before resetting it?
        'Range("B" & Trim(Str(c.Row))).Select
        'Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        lastRow = .Cells(c.Row, 2).End(xlDown).Row 'see how you can skip all the selecting?

        ''just insert the lines directly
        'If Selection.Value = "Period" Then
        If .Cells(lastRow, 2).Value = "Period" Then
            .Rows(lastRow + 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            lastRow = lastRow + 2
        Else
            .Rows(lastRow + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            lastRow = lastRow + 1
        End If

        ''what is this for? Rows("4:4") works but it's unnecessary
        's = s & ":" & s

        ''remove selection
        'Rows(s).Select
        'Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        ''this is what you'd do if you didn't insert the row above
        'Rows(s).Insert Shift:=xlDown

        ''instead of copying, just assign the range
        's = Trim(Str(Selection.Row)) 'why? you don't use it anymore
        'Range("E10").Copy
        'Cells(Selection.Row, 5).Select
        'ActiveSheet.Paste
        'Application.CutCopyMode = False
        .Cells(lastRow, 5) = .Cells(10, 5)

        ''is this really necessary?
        'Range("A" & Trim(Str(c.Row))).Select
        .Cells(c.Row, 1).Select
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But would there not be a way of assigning CurrentRegion to .Rows(lastRow + 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown to count the list of rows in the section as they are going to be a random amount.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. `lastRow = .Cells(c.Row, 2).End(xlDown).Row` takes care of a variable amount of rows. I see no reason to count the number of rows in the current region because you are only interested in the end of the region.

Comment: Yes, but it means that when you add a new line it will always add underneath the 2 skipped ones (title, column title) regardless if any number of lines already in the section.

Comment: You code selects the `End(xlDown)` cell, then selects the row one or two beneath and inserts a row beneath that. My code sets lastRow to the row number of the `End(xlDown)` cell, adds one or two and inserts a row beneath that line number. The two subs do the same thing for me.

Comment: @user3565164 or does the sub not do what you want? Then you should describe what it should do vs. what it does more detailed

Comment: Is there any way of using CurrentRegion to do this?

Comment: @user3565164 Why do you want to use `CurrentRegion`?? You need to explain why what you have is not satisfactory. You can get the last row of the current region using `.CurrentRegion.Row + .CurretRegion.Rows.Count`. Is that what you're asking?